# Ubuntu installation loop

Tags: 14.04, boot

I want to migrate from Windows 10 to Ubuntu (14.04). I downloaded Universal USB Installer and Ubuntu 14.04 from the official site.

I opened the BIOS settings, changed the boot order so that USB would be first, chose to delete the hard drive and installed Ubuntu.

At the end of installation, I was asked to restart the computer and then I was back to the beginning of the installation where I started.

I have since tried to redo the process and didn't work.

I'm stuck in an endless loop of installation and I have no working operating system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe changing from UEFI to Legacy will help.

Comment: If you set the USB to boot before the hard drive, of course it's going to boot back into the installation. You either need to change it back or unplug the thumb drive.

Comment: i thought about it,  but ufter deleting windows, i have nothing to boot from the hard drive. the bootloader gives me only one option - usb.

Comment: What Zacharee1 said, change the boot order in the BIOS settings so that the hard drive to which you installed the bootloader is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a partition problem.

I am not 100% sure what happened but it seems that even i picked "delete windows and install ubuntu instead" it did not install it on the main partition (i'm not sure why there was more than 1).

so instead i picked something like "customized install" where i could see all partitions. i deleted all of them and left only 1 with the whole disk. after that installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party tools often do not create the media properly.

Use the built-in **diskpart** tool from within Windows OS.

Open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file and copy all the content to the USB drive.

When booting from the USB drive select the entry with UEFI.

If you have Ubuntu installed you can do it with the **disks tool**.
Select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right ...
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** ... then start restoring.